# How tu update a JSON with Ionic and WP-API

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic-framework, wp-api

I'm using Wordpress as a backend for my Ionic application.
I get all the data I want from my GET request, however I have a "like" system on my website that I would like to implement everytime a user clicks on it, whether he is authenticated or not.

I really don't get how I can update the field based on WP API.

I've set Basic Authentication on my .htaccess, and every time I make a POST request I get rest-cannot-update error.

Here is how the JSON looks like

```
[
 {
    "metadata": {
            "_edit_lock": [
                "1531733011:13"
            ],
            "_edit_last": [
                "13"
            ],
            "onesignal_meta_box_present": [
                ""
            ],
            "onesignal_send_notification": [
                ""
            ],
            "slider": [
                "1"
            ],
            "_post_like_count": [
                "2"
            ],
 }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Make a basic create post request to verify if your authentication access is working or not.

Comment: Thank you @AtulSharma for your answer. Actually, it doesn't. It works only with GET requests

Comment: What endpoint you are using. Just go to the route of endpoint to verify whether endpoint supports POST method or not. Go to `example.com/wp-json` it will list all endpoints with supported method and data.